# Run two function simultaneously

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an android app that use the bluetooth to connect to two devices. (I'm using BLE-PLX library)

At the moment I use a function to connect to first device, and inside this function another one to connect to the second one. Now the problem is that there is a delay of about 10/15 seconds before the second function starts.

In your opinion how can I do to cancel this delay? 
Imagine that there is another function similar *ScanL()*

```
scansDevices(){
      let promise1 = this.scanDx();
      let promise2 = this.scanSx();
      Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
      .then( () => {
        console.log("Inzio scansione")
      })
      .catch(() => {
        Alert.alert("Errore ScansDevices()");

      });
  }


scanR() {
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        return;
      }

      if(device.name == this.model_sx(this.props.Model)) {
        this.scanR()
      }
      if (device.name == this.model_dx(this.props.Model)) {
        this.setState({rightDevice: device.id})
        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
        device
          .connect()
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        then(() => {
          this.deviceService_Dx(device);
      })
        .catch(() => {
          Alert.alert("ERROR.");
          Actions.homepage();
        });
      })
      }
    });
  }
```

I read that I should use a Promise.all to execute simultaneously these functions, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: *"I read that I should use a Promise.all to execute simultaneously these functions, but I don't know how to do."* - Did the sources you were reading provide some guidance? Perhaps you can elaborate on which part of this you were having trouble with, or share your attempt to implement it. Even though it may be incorrect, it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: @TylerRoper I don't know if it is the right thing to do, especially because the Promise.all Example are only on variable and not with function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay possibly comes from having to wait for the device to connect in order to execute `scanL()`. If you have to wait for it to connect and only use `scanL()` after- your solution is the right way and there is no way to reduce the delay.

However, If you dont and you can the `device.connect()` command and the `scanL()` command at the same time and wait for both of them to complete simultanously- you can use `Promise.all()`.

Promise.all() is a promise that resolves when all promises in an array of promises are resolved, or rejected at the moment one of the promises of the array is rejected.

Example:

```
let promise1 = asyncOp();
let promise2 = asyncOp2();
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then( () => { /*will execute only if and when both promises are resolved */} )
.catch( () => { /* execute if and when *ONE* of the promises is rejected*/} );
```

So to use it, `scanL()` must return a promise.
If it doesn't- you can consider pulling it out of the `.then` clause. The function passed to `.then` is only executed when the promise resolved, but meanwhile the code continues to execute in order from the place the promise was created. If you pull it out of the `then` it will execute it right after creating the promise from the `device.connect()` method, and will not wait for it to resolve.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so for example I can create a general function in which I declare scanR() and scanL() functions?

Comment: @Jack23 yeah you can create a scanAll() function which returns a promise and Inside it call scanL() and scanR() and put the resulted promises in an array. or you can also do something like `return Promise.all([scanL(), scanR()])` if you want it real short and simple. Remember that both scanL() and scanR() have to return a promise themselves in order to be used inside `Promise.all`, and as I can see scanR() does not do so right now.

Comment: @Jack23 also if my answer answered your question and helped you, please tick the green "V" near it to mark it as correct answer :)

Comment: yes Just another little question, could you explain where insert a promise in the ScanL() e ScanR() functions? I edited my first message! :) @Gibor

Comment: @Jack23 it depends on a number of things, like which part of your function you want to be part of the promise and which not (the parts which are outside the promise will be executed synchronously, and the parts inside the promise asynchrnously). If you want all the function to be a promise, just wrap all the code inside: `scanL() { return new Promise ( (resolve,reject) => { /*your code */ } );`
If you're having troubles understanding this line- I suggest you red more about promises before going on ahead :)

Comment: @Jack23 in the code inside your promise you don't use `return` but call the `reject()` function if its an error and you want to reject the promise, and `resolve()` otherwise. You can also pass them values to indicate the error in `reject` or the value you want to return in `resolve` (and you'll get them in the `.catch` and `.then` accordingly as arguments)